# How to update nested array in React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am trying to update my state so that a nested array gets emptied but the rest of the state stays the same.

My state object looks like:

```
this.state = {
    data: {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [1,2,3,4]
    }
}
```

And I the closest I get to working is:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: [...prevState.data, (this.state.data.features.length = 0)]
}));
```

The console warning I get with this approach is:

```
Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()  react/no-direct-mutation-state
```

But how else is this possible?

Many thanks :)

Comment: what are you trying to update ? Are you making the array empty?

Comment: @WillJenkins How do you know that's not in the constructor? I think it is the inner of `setState`.

Comment: @BrianThompson - it tells you to "Use setState()", which you are doing

Comment: But there is also a direct assignment to `this.state.xx` which seems more likely to be the problem.

Comment: yeah, it'll be that one

Comment: @UKS Yes, I just want to make to make the array empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem I see with your code is you're changing `data` from an object to an array. So it should as least be

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: {...prevState.data, (this.state.data.features.length = 0)}
}));
```

Then you're still mutating state by doing `this.state.data.features.length = 0`, so to fix that, you need to update that array immutably:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: {
    ...prevState.data, 
    features: [] // Or whatever you need your new array to be
  }
}));
```

So say you wanted to add another element to the end, you could do:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
  data: {
    ...prevState.data, 
    features: [...prevState.data.features, 5]
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update the state like this. `data` in the state is an object, not an array.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    data: {...prevState.data, features: [] }
}));
```